# What is the caret symbol (^) and where is it defined?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I saw the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^ {
    iv.alpha = 1.0;//iv is a UIImageView
}];
```

Supposedly `^` defines a function block or something.  Is this similar to a delegate?  Is this part of C/C++ or Objective-C?  I cannot option+CLICK this symbol to go to it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caret symbol creates a [block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html), which is similar to a delegate.  It's a type of [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)—a function defined inline that also has access to variables in the parent scope, which can often be used to greatly simplify certain types of delegate-/callback-oriented code.